# I've removed my /author/ slug but it clashes with new and existing pages. Any fixes?

Tags: permalinks, users, redirect, author, slug

I've successfully removed my author slug using this tutorial: https://wp-snippet.com/snippets/remove-author-prefix-from-slug/

so it's like website.com/author/cixxy to website.com/cixxy

My question is, if I have an existing page like website.com/readme , and a new user registers as readme nickname, then his author page will just redirect to the readme page.

Or if they registered already, then I won't be able to use that nickname for a page anymore, right? So if they registered as "Contact" username, I won't be able to have a /contact slug.

How can I prevent this? I see behance.net, facebook etc using both pages as the root and also users, so I'm guessing there has to be a way.

Comment: This is why the author/ part of the URL exists. Do you really need to remove it?

Comment: Well for user sharing their links, it's much better. The site is a portfolio sharing site so it's bad to do website.com/u/user ... looks much better as website.com/user but I need to get around this issue like facebook , behance , etc did.

Comment: Then you have to indicate that this is page, not author: `example.com/page/cixxy` (like Behance do). Anyway, this is useless endeavour.

Comment: @MaxYudin no, behance keeps them all under the root page. And it's not useless like I just pointed out, there's a reason why all the big social media sites do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way around uniqueness being necessary, with the effects you described. Personally I wouldn't remove the part that makes ensuring uniqueness of the slug much easier, like the author part, in my mind it is just a sign of a well structured site. Anyhow, there is [`validate_username()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/validate_username/) function with the [`validate_username`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/validate_username/) hook. You can use it to disallow certain usernames, so e.g. a custom list of stopwords you want to enforce. And you can use it to prevent the registration of usernames, who would be conflicting with other already registered slugs, content.

Comment: Thank you. So basically use plugin like this to stop certain usernames from being registered:  https://wordpress.org/plugins/restrict-usernames/

I guess I'll need a list of pages i'll potentially create in the future as well as existing ones.

Comment: I don't know the plugin, but it looks like it's going in the right direction, and might be (at least partially) suitable. @Cixxy