# How to change the url of the author to a specific page?

Tags: author

I want to change the url of the author to a specific page.

from http://xuzhousoft.com/blog/author/zhuliang/
to http://xuzhousoft.com/zhuliang/

how to do this?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I've removed my /author/ slug but it clashes with new and existing pages. Any fixes?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/313962/ive-removed-my-author-slug-but-it-clashes-with-new-and-existing-pages-any-fi)